# App Crashes on Play Store but not Play Console

Tags: android, google-play-console

I uploaded an aab to the play console and finally got it listed on the play store. This app was written in Python and Kivy, and I was able to generate the aab by first running buildozer then running the script through Android Studio by following various instructions around the net.

I can download an apk from the play console which is generated from the aab, and it works just fine. However, when I install the app from the play store it closes as soon as it opens. However, I dont get a true crash report.

This is my first real app, and I'm a little lost on how to proceed.

Questions:

1. Any idea what's going on here?
2. What's the difference between the apk generated from the play console vs whatever is installed from the play store?
3. How can I diagnose this issue if I don't have access to the apk with the issue?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Kivy, but hopefully there's _something_ in Logcat?

Comment: Are you using any resources which are not compatible for all devices??

Comment: I just realized that buildozer has the ability to create aab's now. That happened quicker than I thought it would. I'm going to try that first to see if it resolves this issue. If that doesn't work, I'll research how to get and read a logcats. I was trying to get a bug report from Developer Options, but I couldn't figure out what to do with the 100MB+ dumpastate text file or any of the other files it generated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by using a dev version of Buildozer to create the aab instead of using Android Studio.

The instructions can be found here by scrolling down to Release Builds:
https://github.com/Android-for-Python/Android-for-Python-Users#how-to-create-a-release-bundle-aab

Answer (score -1):

Use [Firebase Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/products/crashlytics), it logs crashes in the firebase console. You can use it in cases you can't access the apk. It requires some setup but is pretty easy. In your case, however, I think you can see the stacktrace in Android Studio if you set no filter and manually search for your app in LogCat.

Answer (score -2):

Rather than aab upload file in .apk it will properly run.It is not good scenario to use apk bcz it increase the app size.When we use aab file to upload some files are not working bcz of this crash occurs.

Comment: Please, use words, not weird abbreviations

Comment: you know that google will only take aab files in future, right?

Comment: That switch has been made. Google only takes aab files now. I can't upload an apk. I've tried.